# R validate package var_group - define a variable input list?

Tags: r

I am trying to use the validate package to define a set of validation rules.
I have a lot of variables, and there are a lot of rules that apply to the same set of variables repeatedly.

I would like to avoid listing the same (long) lists of variables repeatedly, but I can't figure out how to define a list of variables that var_group will accept.

For example, the following works without issue:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,NA,4,5), B=c(10,NA,30,40,50), C=c(NA,200,300,4,500))

rules <- validator(!is.na(var_group(A,B,C))
                   , var_group(B,C)>= 10)

out <- confront(df, rules)
summary(out)

###output: 

  name items passes fails nNA error warning         expression
1 V1.1     5      4     1   0 FALSE   FALSE          !is.na(A)
2 V1.2     5      4     1   0 FALSE   FALSE          !is.na(B)
3 V1.3     5      4     1   0 FALSE   FALSE          !is.na(C)
4 V2.1     5      4     0   1 FALSE   FALSE (B - 10) >= -1e-08
5 V2.2     5      3     1   1 FALSE   FALSE (C - 10) >= -1e-08
```

However, if I attempt to define "A,B,C" or "B,C" as lists, it reads the list of variables as a text string.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,NA,4,5), B=c(10,NA,30,40,50), C=c(NA,200,300,4,500))

vars_all <- names(df) 
vars_large <- c("B", "C")

rules <- validator(!is.na(var_group(paste(vars_all, collapse=", ")))
                   , var_group(paste(vars_large, collapse=", "))>= 10)

out <- confront(df, rules)
summary(out)

###output: 
  name items passes fails nNA error warning                               expression
1 V1.1     1      1     0   0 FALSE   FALSE !is.na(paste(vars_all, collapse = ", "))
2 V2.1     1      1     0   0 FALSE   FALSE paste(vars_large, collapse = ", ") >= 10
```

I've tried a few different variations on paste, unlist etc.
I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.

Does anyone know how to achieve this outcome? or if there is another package that may provide this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build rules dynamically, you need to pass your rules as character values in a data.frame to the `.data=` parameter

```
rule_data <- data.frame(rule=c(
  paste0("!is.na(var_group(", paste(vars_all, collapse=", "), "))"),
  paste0("var_group(", paste(vars_large, collapse=", "), ")>=10")
))
rules <- validator(.data=rule_data)

out <- confront(df, rules)
summary(out)
```

results in

```
  name items passes fails nNA error warning
1 V1.1     5      4     1   0 FALSE   FALSE
2 V1.2     5      4     1   0 FALSE   FALSE
3 V1.3     5      4     1   0 FALSE   FALSE
4 V2.1     5      4     0   1 FALSE   FALSE
5 V2.2     5      3     1   1 FALSE   FALSE
          expression
1          !is.na(A)
2          !is.na(B)
3          !is.na(C)
4 (B - 10) >= -1e-08
5 (C - 10) >= -1e-08
```